# wrong input argument number in Django login() function

Tags: django, authentication

I'm using Django authentication to do log in. I check the documentation of login() accept 2 input argument request and user. But When I implement the function login(request,user), the error message shows that this function only accept one input argument. What's wrong with my understanding of Django? This is my import

```
from django.contrib.auth import *
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
```

Following is my code

```
def authuser(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username','')
    password = request.POST.get('password','')
    user = authenticate(username = username,password= password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request,user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/timer/clock/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/timer/login/')
```

Comment: Are you using login from django.contrib.auth? Could you show us your imports?

Comment: Thanks for reminding. Yes I'm using django.contrib.auth. The error message is"login() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Comment: do you have any other function named login in your application?

Comment: Thats the problem! I have another function with the same name. You are truly a bug killer Gabriel! Need to learn more about debugging:(( Thanks!@Gabriel Ilharco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, Django's login function from django.contrib.auth takes 2 arguments, so the error you are getting is because the function you are calling is another function named login from your application .